# REST API URI Design for sensitive resources

Tags: api, rest, uri

I have an application backed by RESTFul API. The application have user management section through which an admin user can manage other users. One sample URI for one of the API operation endpoint is below.

Update User  : **POST https://example.com/api/users/user1**

Here **user1** is the Username of the user being edited by the admin.

Suggestion from the security side is to remove the username from the URI since it is sensitive info and since it is part of url it will be recorded in network logs. Solution suggested is to  pass the username data in POST Request Body .

Moving the data to request body is fine. But if I remove the username from URI ,the URI will be like "**POST [https://example.com/api/users**"](https://example.com/api/users**%22) . This clearly doesn't look like a valid REST URI. And my USER entity doesn't have any other unique property which can be used in the URI.

Is there any recommended way to form a proper REST URI in such a scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
POST /api/users
```

> This clearly doesn't look like a valid REST URI.

Sure it does.

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers, so long as the spelling is consistent with the production rules in RFC 3986.

That said, there's no particular reason that the identifier for a document needs to include sensitive information.

There are a couple of possible solutions - if the client and the server both know the sensitive data, then you can use a hashed value, rather than a raw value, as part of your identifier.

That's not ideal: we have mechanical ways of communicating URI that accept parameters, but no standard that I know of for communicating that some value should be hashed first.

If code-on-demand is an option, you might be able to manage to instruct the general purpose client to hash the data before sending it.

Otherwise, I think you are reduced to communicating the hashing out of band -- imagine a web form that instructs the human being to type in the hashed value of the sensitive information.

REST is optimized for the use cases that it was optimized for, and that means that some other use cases are more clumsy than we might like.  Hooray for trade offs.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an "id" instead of "username":

```
https://example.com/api/users/{id}
```

where "id" is usually a UUID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier